# Space of functions that are everywhere differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Define the space $\beta^1([a,b])$ as the space of functions $f : [a,b] \mapsto \Bbb R$ which are everywhere differentiable and whose derivative $f'$ is a bounded function.  One equips this space with the metric $$ d(f,g) = \sup{|f(x)-g(x)|} + \sup{|f'(x) - g'(x)|}$$
Prove that this turns $\beta^1([a,b])$ into a complete metric space.

Please help. I know what a complete metric space is, but I'm having trouble getting started with this proof. Is there a way to do this proof without knowing about Banach spaces? I am stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It may help us if you say more concretely what exactly is giving you trouble. Do you see how one would start a proof of this statement, but get stuck down the line, or are not sure how to even begin the proof? Do you already know that $d$ is a metric, or is this part of the question, or of your difficulty?

Comment: I know that a space is complete if every Cauchy sequence converges, but I don't know how to apply that to this problem. I guess I'm having trouble getting started.

Comment: Is there a different definition or theorem related to complete metric spaces that would be more helpful, that I don't know about?

Comment: For the record, note that this is a Banach space. Your distance comes from a norm.

Comment: So can you prove this is a distance, to begin with? And have your already seen that $C([a,b])$ is a complete normed vector space (i.e. a Banach space) with the sup norm?

Comment: I haven't learned about Banach spaces before, or normed vector spaces.

Comment: So I've read a little about Banach spaces in the past hour.  It is possible to do this proof without knowing about Banach spaces, because we haven't learned them in class and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to prove this with a different method.  Is is true that if I prove it's a Banach space, I prove that it's complete, or am I missunderstanding? How would I go about proving it's a Banach space? Or is there another method?